# How to solve gptboot: No /boot/loader on 0:ad(0p2) issue while installing Freebsd?

Tags: boot, freebsd, virtual-machine, vmware

I have installed FreeBSD 12.0 in vmware virtual machine. After installaion, I am getting below error while booting.

```
gptboot: No /boot/loader on 0:ad(0p2)
gptboot: No /boot/kernel/kernel on 0:ad(0p2)
FreeBSD x86 boot
Default: 0:ad(0p2)/boot/kernel/kernel
boot:
```